# Cannot find module './app.module.ngfactory'.ts(2307)

Tags: angular, module, nativescript, ngfactory

I have uploaded my project here: https://github.com/rezaee/conFusion-test, actually it was an NativeScript-Angular project written in 2017 with version 5 or 6 that I tried to update it to Angular 8, and I did all the job but one file named `main.aot.ts` remained. In that file that has this content:

```
// this import should be first in order to load some required settings (like globals and reflect-metadata)
import { platformNativeScript } from "nativescript-angular/platform-static";

import { AppModuleNgFactory } from "./app.module.ngfactory";

platformNativeScript().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

I get

> Cannot find module './app.module.ngfactory'.ts(2307)

error message. So I tried `npm installng-factory` but it gives me the following error too:

```
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.3.0: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN @angular/http@8.0.0-beta.10 requires a peer of @angular/core@8.0.0-beta.10+1.sha-a28b3e3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/http@8.0.0-beta.10 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@8.0.0-beta.10+1.sha-a28b3e3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN nativescript-angular@8.0.0 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.8.4 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN nativescript-couchbase@1.0.18 requires a peer of tns-core-modules@^3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ ng-factory@1.1.0
updated 1 package and audited 11952 packages in 25.655s
found 169 vulnerabilities (13 low, 2 moderate, 154 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

As I am a new learner and just following a video tutorial I don't know how to solve the problem? Please help me to solve the last error message. Thank you in advanced!

Comment: You don't need `main.aot.ts` anymore (just delete this file). The latest versions of `nativescript-dev-webpack` are post-processing the `main.ts` and configure it for `aot` compilation out of the box when `--env.aot` is specified. Your GitHub URL is not working. I also suggest you directly try the coming NativeScript 6.0.0 release by executing: `npm i nativescript@rc -g` and `tns migrate`.

Comment: @DimitarTachev: Sorry I changed the github link. You can also see here because I did what you say but got new errors: https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/4845